# How to remove all empty elements from a list of list

Tags: python

I have the following list of list in Python and would like to remove all empty elements without invalidating indices.

```
mylist = [['write', 'create', 'draw', 'book', 'mkay', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
            ['hey', 'mykey', 'ange', 'kiki', 'rose', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']]
```

I need the output like this:

```
mylist = [['write', 'create', 'draw', 'book', 'mkay'],
            ['hey', 'mykey', 'ange', 'kiki', 'rose']]
```

I have tried to use the following line of code, but it does not give the expected output.

```
mylist1 = list(filter(None, mylist))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nested list comprehension with a conditional check for the empty string as:

```
new_list = [[s for s in sub_list if s] for sub_list in mylist]
```

**Output**

```
[['write', 'create', 'draw', 'book', 'mkay'],
 ['hey', 'mykey', 'ange', 'kiki', 'rose']]
```

Comment: Thank you so much@Pluviophile, it is giving me the expected output.

Comment: Glad that it helped!! @Angelica

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension for this with a nested list comprehension or using the `filter` function:

```
mylist = [
    [value for value in sublist if value != ""]
    for sublist in mylist
]

mylist = [
    list(filter(lambda x: x != "", sublist))
    for sublist in mylist
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Oxbowerce, it works fine.